# QGIS Exporting geometry of repeated labels of line layer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, export, parallel, repeating

I would like to export geometry (in any format, preferably as a separate point shape, but will work around if necessary) OF LABELS of a line shape layer, where I use repeated labels ("Parallel" labels, repeated at a given "Repeat" distance). Is there a good way to do that, can anybody help?

Comment: Could you just use the points along geometry tool and set the distance to be the same as your labels?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, didn't even think about the Points along Geometry tool. It's not an ideal solution, but it works. Thanks!